# ASP Clássico roda em servidor ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, servidor, iis, asp

Tenho um site todo feito em ASP Clássico e hospedado num provedor.

Meu cliente - que é uma multinacional - quer colocar o site deles dentro do servidor global da empresa e a a diretriz que chegou de fora diz que o servidor roda ASP.NET.

Minha duvida é:

Consigo rodar o meu site (em ASP Clássico) direto no servidor deles (que roda ASP.NET)? Ou é necessário algum ajuste no servidor?

Até onde sei, ASP Clássico e ASP.NET rodam no Windows. Basicamente minha dúvida é, se uma vez rodando ASP.NET posso confirmar que o ASP Clássico vai rodar também? Ou isso não é garantido?

Porque meu medo é que como se trata de um suporte global - e não for garantido que vai rodar - que eles se neguem a fazer os ajustes para rodar alegando qualquer coisa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, é possível, até porque não existe servidor ASP ou ASP.NET, existe o servidor HTTP que tem capacidade de rodar essas tecnologias. No caso, é Windows, certo? Então deve estar rodando IIS. Ele tem capacidade de rodar as duas. Claro que eventualmente terá que fazer a configuração corretamente para suportar da forma que precisa, mas provavelmente o padrão já rodará.

Claro que só vendo como está. Há quem desabilite qualquer coisa desnecessária, e principalmente tecnologias legadas, como é o caso do ASP. Isso é feito por uma boa razão e eu veria com bons olhos que recusassem habilitar por causa da sua necessidade específica. Nada contra você, claro:) Mas a segurança e simplicidade devem vir antes.

Se precisar rodar alguns componentes extras para dar mais funcionalidade, eles precisarão ser instalados nesse servidor. É comum isso acontecer. Eles farão o que você precisa, se for necessário?

Você terá acesso ao servidor? Poderá fazer o que precisa?

Se precisar de informações específicas, vai postando novas perguntas aqui no site que a gente ajuda. Não tem como dar uma resposta que diz tudo o que fazer, sem ao menos sabermos se ela será relevante.

É difícil responder melhor este tipo de pergunta, já que depende muito do ambiente. Eu falei que funciona, mas pode ser que não funcione dependendo da configuração que está lá.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

O IIS suporta nativamente ambos os environments e geralmente os serviços de hospedagens e administradores de sistemas recurso `ASP Clássico` habilitado contudo, não é uma premissa.

Se a funcionalidade não estiver habilitado e você não possuir acesso as configurações do servidor acredito que um breve ticket para os responsáveis pela infraestrutura resolva o seu problema.

Segue o procedimento para habilitar páginas em `ASP Clássico` no `IIS 6.0` ou superior:

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc737992(v=ws.10).aspx